# Why is the config file in /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/ ignored?

Tags: mysql, munin

I have a Munin script `/etc/munin/plugins/mysql_replag` that queries a MySQL server to check the status of a master-slave replication:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Plugin to monitor the Seconds_Behind_Master of replication on a MySQL slave

MYSQLOPTS="$mysqlopts"
MYSQL=${mysql:-mysql}
if [ "$1" = "autoconf" ]; then
        $MYSQL --version 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
                $MYSQL $MYSQLOPTS -e '' 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]
                then
                        echo yes
                        exit 0
                else
                        echo "no (could not connect to mysql)"
                fi
        else
                echo "no (mysql not found)"
        fi
        exit 1
fi

if [ "$1" = "config" ]; then
        echo 'graph_title Replication lag'
        echo 'graph_args --base 1000 -l 0'
        echo 'graph_vlabel lag in secs'
        echo 'graph_category mysql'
        echo 'lag.label lag'
        exit 0
fi

/usr/bin/printf "lag.value "
mysql $MYSQLOPTS -e 'show slave status\G' | grep Seconds_Behind_Master | awk '{print $2}'
```

The plugin config file is `/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/mysql_replag`: *(note: edited)*

```
[mysql_replag]
user root
env.mysqlopts -umyuser -pmyp4ssw0rd -h 10.13.13.13
```

However, the plugin config file is apparently ignored when running the plugin:

```
# munin-run mysql_replag 
lag.value ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

The plugin works when I remove the MySQL options from the config file and I specify them in the plugin directly via the `$MYSQLOPTS` variable. Why is the config file ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in munin are declared using env.myvariable, not env.var myvariable; try this:

```
env.mysqlopts -umyuser -pmyp4ssw0rd -h 10.13.13.13
```

Comment: Hmmm, strange. I now realize that my config file on the server uses the correct syntax while my question used the wrong syntax. Either I made a mistake copying or I realized my error on the server but forgot to update the question. +1 anyway as your suggestion is good even if it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: It is working now. It appears that I made a mistake in the config file name. Marking your answer as accepted since it allowed me to find the error.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to configure `mysql_queries` plugin using this format, because that is what I found under `/usr/share/munin/plugins/mysql_`

```
[mysql*]

env.mysqluser MyUser
env.mysqlpassword MyPassword
```

Thanks to Patrice Levesque's response I realised that some Mysql munin plugins (e.g `mysql_queries`) use this format:

```
[mysql_queries]
env.mysqlopts -uMyUser -pMyPassword
```